# The column was specified multiple times for 't'

Tags: ef-core-3.1

Once I upgrade my entity framework core to the latest, I cannot execute below query.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df0pa.png)

var result = db.Actuacion.Where(m => m.ActId == id && m.TempSave != true).Include(m => m.Medico).Include(m=>m.Factura).FirstOrDefault();

Factura and Medico has the same column Name and then EF throw below exception to me
"The column 'PCIVA' was specified multiple times for 't'.

How can I get rid of this